# Python program for Wang Landau Algorithm halting after a point

Tags: python, function, infinite-loop, montecarlo, mtrace

I wrote a python code to execute Wang Landau algorithm on 3D polymers. Hereby is attached the relevant codes.

1)The Original Code: WL3D.py

```
from scipy import *
import sys
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from spinfun import SARW
from spinfun import Energy
from spinfun import Transform
from spinfun import Equality

Niter = int(input("Enter number of MC steps:"))
L=int(input("Enter number of monomers:"))
N=int(input("Enter the dimensions of lattice:"))
spin=zeros((N,N,N), dtype=int)

#1)Initialisation of lattice
#Gx,Gy,Gz=SARW(spin,N)
Gx=[300, 300, 300, 299, 299, 298, 297, 297, 298, 299, 299, 299, 299, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 298, 299, 300, 300, 300, 299, 299, 299, 300, 300, 299, 299, 299, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 299, 299, 298, 297, 297, 298, 299, 299, 299, 299, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 298, 299, 300, 300, 300, 299, 299, 299, 300, 300, 299, 299, 299, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]
Gy=[300, 301, 302, 302, 301, 301, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 301, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 301, 300, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 302, 303, 303, 302, 302, 302, 301, 301, 301, 302, 302, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 301, 302, 302, 301, 301, 301, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 301, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 302, 301, 300, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 302, 303, 303, 302, 302, 302, 301, 301, 301, 302, 302, 301, 300, 300, 300]
Gz=[300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 299, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 299, 300, 300, 299, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 298, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 299, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 299, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 299, 300, 300, 299, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 298, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 299, 298, 298, 298, 298, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 299]
for p in range(50):
    spin[Gx[p],Gy[p],Gz[p]]=1
E1=Energy(Gx,Gy,Gz,spin)
print "Initial energy of system is",E1
f1=open("Initial_Data.txt",'w')
for i in range(len(Gx)):
    f1.write("%d %d %d \n"%(Gx[i],Gy[i],Gz[i]))
f1.close()

#2) Matrices and terms required
Ener=(arange(59)-58).tolist()  #List of energy values
E0=-58 #GRound state
lngE=zeros(len(Ener),dtype=float) #LogG
Hist=zeros(len(Ener),dtype=float)
lnf=1.0
#3)The WLA

for time in range(Niter):
    i2=0
    while i2 < L:
        #E1=Energy(Gx,Gy,Gz,spin)
        Gx1,Gy1,Gz1=Transform(Gx,Gy,Gz,spin)   #Attempting a random move
        E2=Energy(Gx1,Gy1,Gz1,spin)   #Energy calculation of changed configuration
        P = exp(lngE[E1-E0]-lngE[E2-E0]) #Acceptance probability
        if P > uniform(0,1):
            Gx,Gy,Gz=Equality(Gx1,Gy1,Gz1)
            print 'Ok', Gx[0],Gy[0],Gz[0],E1,E2,time,i2
            E1=E2
        else:
            spin[Gx1[0],Gy1[0],Gz1[0]]=0
            spin[Gx[49],Gy[49],Gz[49]]=1
            print 'Not Ok',Gx[0],Gy[0],Gz[0],E1,E2,time,i2
        Hist[E1-E0] += 1.0
        lngE[E1-E0] += lnf
        i2=i2+1
    if time % 1000 == 0:
        Ha = sum(Hist)/(len(Hist))
        Hmin = min(Hist)
        if Hmin > 0.8*Ha:
            print time,'Histogram is flat', Hmin, Ha, 'f=',exp(lnf),'lnf=',lnf
            Hist=zeros(len(Hist))
            lnf=lnf/2.0
            if abs(lnf-0.0) < 0.00000001:
                break
        else:
            print time,'Not flat',Hmin, Ha, 'f=',exp(lnf),'lnf=',lnf



f=open("Final_Data.txt",'w')
for i5 in range(len(lngE)):
    f.write("%f %f \n"%(Ener[i5],lngE[i5]))
f.close()
```

Below is the code "spinfun.py" which has the functions used in above code.

```
from scipy import *
import sys
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
spin=zeros((50,50,50), dtype=int)

Gx2=[25,25,25,24,24,23,22,22,23,24,24,24,24,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,24,25,25,25,24,24,24,25,25,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25]                                 
Gy2=[25,26,27,27,26,26,26,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,26,25,25,25,26,26,26,25,25,26,26,26,27,28,28,27,27,27,26,26,26,27,27,26,25,25,25]
Gz2=[25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,24,23,22,22,22,22,22,23,24,25,25,24,23,23,23,23,22,22,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,23,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,22,23,24]
#A,B,C=np.loadtxt("Self2_trials.txt",usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True,dtype=int)

#########
def SARW(spin,N):
    g2=1
    g1=0
    i=N/2;j=N/2;k=N/2
    Gx=[N/2];Gy=[N/2];Gz=[N/2]
    spin[N/2,N/2,N/2]=1
    while g2 < 50:
        h=uniform(0,1)
        if 0.0 <= h <= 0.167:
            k=k+1
        elif 0.167 <= h <= 0.334:
            j=j+1
        elif 0.334 <= h <= 0.501:
            i=i+1
        elif 0.501 <= h <= 0.668:
            i=i-1
        elif 0.668 <= h <= 0.835:
            j=j-1
        else:
            k=k-1
        if spin[i,j,k] == 0:
            print 'Ok',i,j,k,h,g2
            spin[i,j,k]=1
            Gx=Gx+[i]
            Gy=Gy+[j]
            Gz=Gz+[k]
            g2=g2+1
        else:
            print 'Not Ok',i,j,k,h
            if 0.0 <= h <= 0.167:
                k=k-1
            elif 0.167 <= h <= 0.334:
                j=j-1
            elif 0.334 <= h <= 0.501:
                i=i-1
            elif 0.501 <= h <= 0.668:
                i=i+1
            elif 0.668 <= h <= 0.835:
                j=j+1
            else:
                k=k+1
        g1=g1+1
    return Gx,Gy,Gz
############

def Energy(Gx,Gy,Gz,spin):
    S=0
    Su=[]
    for i in range(50):
        i1=Gx[i]
        j1=Gy[i]
        k1=Gz[i]
        n=spin[i1+1,j1,k1]+spin[i1-1,j1,k1]+spin[i1,j1+1,k1]+spin[i1,j1-1,k1]+spin[i1,j1,k1+1]+spin[i1,j1,k1-1]
        S=S+n
        Su=Su+[n]
        E1=(S-98)/2
        E=-E1
    return E

###########

def Transform(Gx,Gy,Gz,spin):
    Gx1=[];Gy1=[];Gz1=[]
    m=0
    while m < 50:
        Gx1=Gx1+[Gx[m]]
        Gy1=Gy1+[Gy[m]]
        Gz1=Gz1+[Gz[m]]
        m=m+1
    i=Gx1[0];j=Gy1[0];k=Gz1[0]
    g=0
    g1=0
    while g < 1:
        h=uniform(0,1)
        if 0.0 <= h <= 0.167:
            k=k+1
        elif 0.167 <= h <= 0.334:
            j=j+1
        elif 0.334 <= h <= 0.501:
            i=i+1
        elif 0.501 <= h <= 0.668:
            i=i-1
        elif 0.668 <= h <= 0.835:
            j=j-1
        else:
            k=k-1
        if spin[i,j,k] == 0:
            spin[i,j,k]=1
            spin[Gx1[49],Gy1[49],Gz1[49]]=0
            for i1 in range(50):
                n1=49-i1
                if n1 != 0:
                    Gx1[n1]=Gx1[n1-1]
                    Gy1[n1]=Gy1[n1-1]
                    Gz1[n1]=Gz1[n1-1]
                else:
                    Gx1[n1]=i;Gy1[n1]=j;Gz1[n1]=k
            g=g+1
        else:
            if 0.0 <= h <= 0.167:
                k=k-1
            elif 0.167 <= h <= 0.334:
                j=j-1
            elif 0.334 <= h <= 0.501:
                i=i-1
            elif 0.501 <= h <= 0.668:
                i=i+1
            elif 0.668 <= h <= 0.835:
                j=j+1
            else:
                k=k+1
        g1=g1+1
    return Gx1,Gy1,Gz1
########
def Equality(Gx,Gy,Gz):
    Gx1=[];Gy1=[];Gz1=[]
    for m in range(50):
        Gx1=Gx1+[Gx[m]]
        Gy1=Gy1+[Gy[m]]
        Gz1=Gz1+[Gz[m]]
    return Gx1,Gy1,Gz1
```

SO here is the problem I m facing right now. When I am executing the code, the code runs fine but it suddenly stops at a particular step. The code doesn't return any exception or error and it doesn't terminate so I have to kill the execution.

I searched for answers, and I tried the following command to trace the workings of the code.

```
python -m trace --trace WL3D.py
```

The above line obviously ran into bunch of statements printed, and after some lines it started executing the code. This is where it wanted to test the code with inputs. So I gave the necessary inputs and it is now running an infinite loop.

I am unable to trace back as to which portion of the algorithm is sending the code in an infinite loop. Is there any other possible way to work it out? Any help is much appreciated.

P.S: I want you to add the following details when you are running the code.

Enter number of MC steps: You can give any integer whichever you want.

Enter number of monomers: 50 ( I have written this code to first work for 50 monomers of the polymer)

Enter the dimensions of lattice : 600 (You can use any integer, but for the way I have sent the code, 600 is required. You can use any integer if u comment the lines 17-21 and uncomment line 16)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a complicated code, and I don't really understand what the different parts are supposed to do, but I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `Transform` function. If you add a counter to the while loop you'll see that sometimes the `g < 1` condition will keep on being true and the code will never exit the loop. I have noticed that you initialise and then update `g1`, but you never use it. Maybe you forgot to add something that connects `g` and `g1`?

Comment: Sorry but yeah the code seems complicated coz its not the optimized yet.                      Regarding the stuff you pointed out, Here 'g' is used as a control variable to ensure that the if condition is satisfied once before exiting the loop and returned by the function .I didnt think of analysing it well I think, will work on it and see if that sorts out the problem